Do orthogonal trivializations induce orthonormal frames?
Let $E$ be a real vector bundle with a bundle metric $g$ over $M$, and $\{U_i,\phi_i\}$ an orthogonal trivialization; that is for all $i$ and $j$ we have that the map $\phi_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb R)$ given by $p\mapsto \phi_i\circ\phi_{j}^{-1}|_p$ lands in $O(n)$. Let $u_i$ be the standard orthonormal basis on $\mathbb R^n$
Does it then follow that for all $i$, the frame $\{e_j\}$ induced by $e_j(p)=\phi_i^{-1}(p,u_j)$ is an orthonormal frame for $E$ over $U$? I know that if we fix a cover of $E$ of $U_i$ and put local orthonormal frames on each $U$ then we have that trivializations induced by these frames (i.e. $\psi:a^ie_i(p)\mapsto (p,(a_1,\dots, a_n))$ have transition functions in $O(n)$, but I am wondering if we can go the other way.
What I have attempted so far:

$\phi_j\circ \phi_i^{-1}(p,u_k)=\phi_j(e_k(p))$, and that $\phi_i\circ \phi_j^{-1}(p,u_k)=\phi_i(f_k(p))$, where $f_k$ is the frame induced by $\phi_j$. We have that $\phi_i(f_k(p))=A^l_ku_l$ for some matrix $A^l_k$, and this matrix is actually orthogonal as:
$$A^l_ku_i=\phi_i\circ \phi_j^{-1}(p,u_k)=(\phi_i\circ \phi_j^{-1})|_p(u_k)$$
so $A^l_k=(\phi_i\circ\phi_j^{-1})|_p$, hence  $\phi_i^{-1}|_p(A^l_ku_l)=A^l_ke_l(p)=f_k(p)$

However, from here I am quite lost for what to do, and any help (or a counter example) would be much appreciated.

Two frames that differ by an orthogonal transformation certainly need not themselves be orthonormal.

@TedShifrin I agree with this statement. Is the claim false then?

The definition given certainly seems wrong. You need a reduction of the structure group from $GL(n)$ to $O(n)$.

@TedShifrin The existence of such a trivializing cover is a reduction form the structure group though

How do the overlap cocycles give that?

@TedShifrin If ${\phi_i,U_i}$ is a trivializing cover such that $\phi_{ij}(U_i\cap U_j)\subset G\subset GL(\mathbb R^n)$ for all $i$ and $j$ then that is the definition of a $G$ structure on $E$ so gives a $G$ reduction of the structure group

I’m used to thinking of principal bundles. But yes, you’re right. This is an equivalent notion, so then that answers your question immediately.

@TedShifrin How does this answer my question immediately

Didn’t we just agree that the transition function condition gives an $O(n)$-structure?

@TedShiffrin yes I agree the transition function condition gives an $O(n)$ structure, but does that mean that these local sections I've defined are orthonormal?

No. We're back to my original comment. What is true is that given the transition functions, if $M$ is connected and $\phi_1$ is chosen to give you an orthonormal framing of $U_1$, then your desired outcome will follow. However, it certainly does not follow for a general choice of $\phi_i$. In particular, they could all give rise to orthogonal, but not orthonormal, framings ... or worse yet. (The equivalent definitions of $G$-structure tell us that given $\phi_{ij}$ mapping to $G$, we can construct $\phi_i$ giving the $G$-structure.)
